# Multiple jquery UI datepickers on page but need only those used to return a date

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have three jquery UI datepickers on a form on one page which work fine. But I want only one of them to require a date to be selected.
When the non-required ones are left blank and the form is submitted they return a default date of 30-11-0001. Is it possible to return a null date (blank)?

For context, this is a form to announce baby showers. Details after the form is submitted are posted to another page. The form provides for up to three events to be posted. Each has a datepicker field. For those people who only have one event (or two events) to announce, I need the remaining unused form group to return nothing. The other fields in the group do this -- they are merely text fields. But datepicker always returns the default date 30-11-0001.

I haven't tried this so don't know if it would work, but have considered a workaround using jquery show/hide to restructure the form so instead of having all three events available, I would add a "Add another event" button which would reveal a second (and third if clicked again) available event field.

Each event group looks like this:

```
             <h3> <?php echo __('Event 1', GIFTREGISTRY_TEXT_DOMAIN) ?></h3>

             <div class="form-field">
                 <label for="event_datetime"><?php echo __('Date', GIFTREGISTRY_TEXT_DOMAIN) ?><span
                             class="required">*</span></label>
                 <input required name="event_date_time" id="event_date_time" class="date-picker" type="text"
                        value="<?php if (is_object($wishlist)) {
                            $eventdate = new DateTime($wishlist->event_date_time);
                            echo $eventdate->format('d-m-Y');
                        } ?>" size="40">
             </div>

             <div class="form-field">
                 <label for="event_location"><?php echo __('Time & Location', GIFTREGISTRY_TEXT_DOMAIN) ?></label>
                 <input name="event_location" id="event_location" type="text"
                        value="<?php if (is_object($wishlist)) : echo $wishlist->event_location; endif; ?>"
                        size="40">
             </div>

             <div class="form-field">
                 <label for="message"><?php echo __('Message for Guests', GIFTREGISTRY_TEXT_DOMAIN) ?></label>
                 <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="" cols=""><?php
                     if (is_object($wishlist)) : echo $wishlist->message; endif;
                     ?></textarea>
             </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.datepicker("getDate");` if no date was chosen it will return `null`

see [here](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate)